# Потоки и очередь сообщений

Tags: java, rs232, com-port

Задача такая:

Есть com-порт, с которого непрерывно идут данные и необходимо эти данные записывать в базу данных. Важно не пропустить какие-либо данные.

Есть идея сделать так:
организовать два потока, - один будет считывать непрерывно данные, другой записывать в бд.

Думаю, можно будет организовать синхронизацию данных между двумя потоками с помощью коллекции queue.

Целесообразно ли поступить так? Может есть варианты более лучше?

Comment: Надо понимать, что в многозадачной ОС вам никто не обязан предоставлять процессор с нужной вам частотой. Поэтому данные вы всегда можете потерять (ОС решила обновится, еще какое высокоприоритетное случилось). Если это страшно, то надо использовать ОС реального времени, а там ява скорее всего не работает :) и ваш вопрос снимается сам собой. Если же всё не так критично, то надо сделать максимальный приоритет у процесса, который будет читать и поэтому надо писать два процесса - один читает данные в ОЗУ, другой у него эту очередь запрашивает и пихает в базу.

Comment: Учитывая что сом-порт генерирует данные со скоростью 11кбайт/с максимум, то сохранять их в базу можно любым удобным способом.
Какая-нибудь коллекция из java.util.concurrent, один поток слушает сом-порт, вычитывает данные и вставляет в коллекцию. Второй поток читает из коллекции и записывает в базу.